Excel VBA hangs for 10-15 seconds after updating links in word document
I have an excel spreadsheet with some data and related tables & charts, and I also have some associated word documents with links back to these excel objects.
If the files are moved then the links become broken, so I have written a VBA routine to update these links, using code ideas widely available on the web. This works fine - but excel hangs for about 10-15 seconds after the routine completes. I cannot find the reason why.
Code is here:
Sub ConnectReportDocument()
'
Dim objWdApp As Object
Dim objWdDoc As Object
Dim iFieldCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim sWordFilePath As String
Dim dialog As FileDialog
'
'
' Prompt the user for the document to be connected to this workbook
'
    Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dialog
        .Title = "Select the Word Document to be linked to this workbook"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Word Documents", "*.doc; *.docx; *.docm"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            sWordFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected. Operation cancelled."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
'
'
' Open the selected Word document
'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If objWdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set objWdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
'
'
' Disable alerts when we open the file, then re-enable
'
    objWdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
    objWdApp.Visible = True
    Set objWdDoc = objWdApp.Documents.Open(sWordFilePath)
    objWdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll

    With objWdDoc
       iFieldCount = .Fields.Count
          For i = 1 To iFieldCount
          With .Fields(i)
             If .Type = 56 Then
                .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
                .Update
                DoEvents
             End If
          End With
       Next i
    End With
'
'
' Save and close the Word document, and then clean up
'
    objWdDoc.Save
    objWdDoc.Close
    objWdApp.Quit
'
    Set objWdDoc = Nothing
    Set objWdApp = Nothing

End Sub




I have searched for any similar issue on stack overflow and elsewhere but can find nothing. I'm wondering whether excel is actually stuck waiting for something, and then timing out - but I can't see what.
There is only one instance of word running when this happens, and it completes and exits promptly at the end of the VBA routine.

Having data linked between Office documents can be slow, so this doesn't surprise me that much. I'm not sure there's anything you could do reduce the that waiting time.
